# Error in POM.xml file while importing it in eclipse

Tags: android, maven, atmosphere

This is my POM.xml,and i am getting error at 
line 1 and 
at packaging tag as "unknown packaging : apk"

Tried every possible solution ie. installed m2e plugin,managed maven lifecycle,but of no use in eclipse.

Please help!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
        <artifactId>wasync-project</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../../</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.atmosphere.wasync.samples</groupId>
    <artifactId>android-chat</artifactId>
    <packaging>apk</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Android Chat</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
            <artifactId>wasync</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.5.2</version>
                    <extensions>true</extensions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <run>
                        <debug>true</debug>
                    </run>
                    <sdk>
                        <platform>4.0.3</platform>
                        <path>D:\Android\sdk</path>
                    </sdk>
                    <emulator>
                        <avd>15</avd>
                    </emulator>
                    <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: are you using maven 3?

Comment: Does it work when you run maven in command line? i.e. mvn clean install?